# Error WSAStartup con GitKraken

Tags: git, windows10, gitkraken-git-gui

quería saber si alguna vez habéis usado este programa y os ha dado este error, o simplemente os habéis topado con este error y sabéis cómo solventarlo.

Me he percatado que sale sólo cuando hago una acción con el repositorio remoto. Falla con todos los repositorios que he probado.

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> La aplicación no ha llamado a WSAStartup, o bien se ha producido un
> error en WSAStartup.

[image: Captura del error WSAStartup con GitKraken]

He intentando introduciendo lo siguiente en el CMD con permisos de admin y reiniciar:

> netsh winsock reset

Pero sigue funciona una sola vez, la siguiente vez que quiera hacer pull, push, fetch o lo que quiera que sea con remoto, me sale este error.

Comment: ¿Como lo solucionaste?

Comment: Sorry, hace años de esto, y no recuerdo si quiera si se solucionó o usamos otro repositorio :(